# Could things be broken by adding a folder in /home

Tags: directory

If I was to create a folder in `/home` with this command:

```
sudo mkdir /home/newuser
```

would it break anything because I didn't create it in the correct manner - adding a new user? Or would they system simply ignore it (or not notice it is there)?

Comment: I think they it would ignore it until a user with the same name was created, then bugs would appear. But I'm not sure. Try it in a VM where it doesn't matter if you make it go BOOM! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A directory in `/home` is just like any other directory. Without a corresponding entry in the `passwd` database (whether the file itself or in AD) it has no special status. I have made directories there by accident (a `cd` too many) with no side effects. Of course, for all our LDAP users we create the home directories manually in the NFS server, copy over `/etc/skel`, then do a `chown` and other things. When the user logs in, they use their home directories normally.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before, with no negative effects.

I have a set of virtual servers and I log in to them by authenticating with LDAP. Some of the VMs are not configured correctly and don't create a home directory when a new LDAP user logs in.

So in the past I have logged in, created a directory in `/home` that matches my username. Then when I log back in it treats it as my home directory.
However, all those user files like `.bashrc` that are usually created in a home dir are not there. Which is to be expected.

You also need to change the permissions of the directory so it matches a home directory.